# create column for a table from select data from another table column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that shows the date information of a topic.

`FirstTable` looks like this:

| id | DateP |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1397/01/02 |
| 2 | 1398/05/09 |
| 3 | 1398/06/07 |
| 4 | 1398/08/09 |
| 5 | 1399/02/01 |

I want to create columns for another table that are the result of selecting the DateP column from FirstTable.

`SecondTable` looks like this:

| id | 1397/01/02 | 1398/05/09 | 1398/06/07 | 1398/08/09 | 1399/02/01 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |

I am trying below but no success.

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0;
DECLARE @DatTim NVARCHAR(50)='';
SELECT @count=  Count(*) FROM FirstTable

WHILE @i <= @count
BEGIN
    @DatTim=(select DateP+TimeP FROM FirstTable where id=@i)   
    ALTER TABLE SecondTable ADD @DatTim NVARCHAR(50);
    SET @i = @i + 1;
END
```

Please guide me in finding the SQL code.

Comment: Whatever you are trying to achieve, it is rather unconventional. Why do you need it as a table ? Can you accept if a query to produce that pivoted result ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the members, thank God, I was able to find a solution

```
DECLARE @i INT = 1;
DECLARE @count INT = 0;
DECLARE @DatTim NVARCHAR(50)='';
Set @count=(select Count(*) FROM FirstTable)

WHILE @i <= @count
BEGIN
    Set @DatTim=(select DateP FROM FirstTable where id=@i)   
    exec ('ALTER TABLE SecondTable ADD ['+@DatTim +'] int NULL')
    SET @i = @i + 1;
END
```